# Cannot animate text color to earlier value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have animated a specific text to white with this code:

```
$("a:contains('Contact')").animate({color: 'white'},200);
```

and then I want to change the #links ul li a to black (the Contact is also in it) with this code:

```
$('links a').animate({color: 'black'},200);
```

But somehow it does not change back the whole row / contact to black

how can I fix this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your HTML, please.

Comment: Which plugin do you use to animate the color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

You have missed id selector in your script.

```
$('#links ul li a').animate({color: 'black'}, 200);
```

Comment: Looks like i misunderstood question and issue was just a typo

Comment: A. Wolff Lets say I cannot animate the #links ul li a and I want to know why I cannot, and how it can be fixed

Comment: @FlyingUnderpants, Can you please provide your code in jsfiddle example?

Comment: No I just cannot make it work but here is the javascript, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Hover over links 
$('#links a, #footerMenuList a').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({color: 'white'},200);
});

$('#links a, #footerMenuList a').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({color: '#9099af'},200);
});

//Check if div in on the screen and highlight specific link

//Get top of div
//Get Bottom of div
//Get window top
//Get window Bottom
//Check if Y coörds are in windows
//Highlight specif link
var win = $(window);

//Give all boxes properties
 var services = {
    top: $('#services').position().top,
    bottom: $('#services').position().top + $('#services').height()
};   

var portfolio = {
    top: $('#portfolio').position().top,
    bottom: $('#portfolio').position().top + $('#portfolio').height()
};

var buy = {
    top: $('#buy').position().top,
    bottom: $('#buy').position().top + $('#buy').height()
};

var about = {
    top: $('#about').position().top,
    bottom: $('#about').position().top + $('#about').height()
};

var footer = {
    top: $('#footer').position().top,
    bottom: $('#footer').position().top + $('#footer').height()
};

var winHeight = win.height();
var winTop = win.scrollTop();
var winBottom = winHeight + winTop;

if(winTop === 0) {
    $('links ul li a').css('color','#9099af');
    $("a:contains('Home')").animate({color: 'white'},200);
};

//check which is on screen 
win.scroll(function(){
    winHeight = win.height();
    winTop = win.scrollTop();
    winBottom = winHeight + winTop; 


    if(services.top > winTop) {
        if(services.bottom < winBottom) {
            $('links ul li a').animate({color: '#9099af'},200);
            $("a:contains('Services')").animate({color: 'white'},200);
        };
    };

    if(portfolio.top > winTop) {
        if(portfolio.bottom < winBottom) {
            $('links ul li a').animate({color: '#9099af'},200);
            $("a:contains('Portfolio')").animate({color: 'white'},200);
        };
    };

    if(buy.top > winTop) {
        if(buy.bottom < winBottom) {
            $('links ul li a').animate({color: '#9099af'},200);
            $("a:contains('Buy')").animate({color: 'white'},200);
        };
    };

    if(about.top > winTop) {
        if(about.bottom < winBottom) {
            $('links ul li a').animate({color: '#9099af'},200);
            $("a:contains('About')").animate({color: 'white'},200);
        };
    };

    if(footer.top > winTop) {
        if(footer.bottom < winBottom) {
            $('links ul li a').animate({color: '#9099af'},200);
            $("a:contains('Contact')").animate({color: 'white'},200);
        };
    };

    if(winTop === 0) {
        $('links ul li a').animate({color: '#9099af'},200);
        $("a:contains('Home')").animate({color: 'white'},200);
    };

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue of specificity. The animations set the styles directly on the elements. So if you animate an element to white, and an ancestor of that element to black, the style set directly on the element (white) will always trump the style set on the ancestor (black).

In other words, you need to remove the style set on the element, or animate it back to its orginal value, along the lines of `$( "a:contains('Contact')" ).animate( { color: 'black' }, 200 );`.

This is assuming that the basic color animation works, ie that you have [a plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) in place to handle it. jQuery [can't handle color animations](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties) out of the box.